# After upgrade to Lion, Mailplane experiences repeated failures to connect

Tags: macos

I'm a happy longtime Mailplane (Mac gmail client) user, but it seems to have become buggy since installing Lion.

There's nothing official on the website about problems, so maybe its just me and/or my configuration.

Anybody else have problems? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problems you're experiencing?

Comment: Are you using the OS X firewall?

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I have been using Mailplane on Lion on my MacBooks (Air&Pro) without any bugginess. (Have you contacted the dev? He's been very responsive in my experience.)

If you didn't do a clean install of Lion (or used MobileMe to sync preferences) you might want to backup

- ${HOME}/Library/Application Support/Mailplane
- ${HOME}/Library/Preferences/com.mailplaneapp.Mailplane.plist

(If you don't have your license file, be sure to save

```
defaults read com.mailplaneapp.Mailplane License
```

too.)

zip/email them to yourself and then delete them -- not just trash them -- from your system. Reboot.

Then try setting up Mailplane again.

Comment: My main issue has been repeated failures to connect. I get the "trying again in 20 secs, 19 secs...) etc. But when I use a browser window adjacent to MP it works fine.

Comment: I will try these steps now. Thanks for your response.